# Where clause in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, http-post

I have the following code that selects a bunch of comments from a database, but I only ever have one current post and I would like to deal only with comments regarding the current Post.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.PostCommentFK = new SelectList(db.Posts, "PostID", "PostTitle");
    return View();
}
```

I guess all I need is to add a where clause to the statement, “PostCurrent” is a Boolean and there can only ever be one “True” PostCurrent.

Currently in my view I have a hidden field with the value of 1 in it, so comments are only added to post 1, but would like that to be the current post.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PostCommentFK, new { Value = 1 })
```

I then have a `[HttpPost]` method to SaveChanges,

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(Comment comment)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         db.Comments.AddObject(comment);
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("CommentResponse");  
     }

    ViewBag.PostCommentFK = new SelectList(db.Posts, "PostID", "PostTitle", comment.PostCommentFK);
    return View(comment);
}
```

Comment: what is your question

Comment: How do I retrieve the PostID of the current post and insert it into the FK field of the new comment? PostCurrent is a Boolean field in the Post table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to hide `PostID` instead `value`

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PostCommentFK.PostID)
```

Then :

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(Comment comment)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         if(comment.PostID == 0)//New record
            db.Comments.AddObject(comment);
         else // Edit existing comment
            {
              var OldComment = db.Comments.Where(c => c.PostID == comment.PostID).SingleOrDefault();
              if (OldComment != null)
                {
                  OldComment.PostTitle = comment.PostTitle;
                  //Set all other properties...
                }
            }
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("CommentResponse");  
     }

    ViewBag.PostCommentFK = new SelectList(db.Posts, "PostID", "PostTitle", comment.PostCommentFK);
return View(comment);
}
```

Comment: I can’t get that to work because I haven’t selected the CurrentPosts, PostID at any stage.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Amen,

You were close and it pointed me in the right direction. The problem I had was in my view I was using a comment modal but needed a post modal. The view posts comments but is just a form and only needs to know about the PostID of the CurrentPost.

So I changed my Index action to,

```
public ActionResult Index()
{            
    Post post = db.Posts.Single(p => p.PostCurrent == true);
    return View(post);
}
```

And gave my view a Post Modal

```
@model TMPBlog.Models.Post
```

I could then access the PostID like this,

```
@Html.Hidden("PostCommentFK", @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PostID))
```

Cheers,

Mike.